# Javascript variable, different values, same line

Tags: javascript, android, mysql

First of all, let me apologize for the title, as it isn't so explanatory, but I could not say it in another way.

The deal is: I am doing a javascript application, in which I have an object called "ocorrencia", which was defined like this:

```
var ocorrencia = new Object();
```

that object has several children, being filled by a method:

```
ocorrencia.idOcorrencia = ""+ year + month + day + hour + minute + second + milisec;
```

idOcorrencia is the one I am having problems with, because I am running a DataBase insert with this value, and I use it 2 times in the same insert, like:

```
var sql = 'INSERT INTO OCORRENCIAS (id, ocorrencia, data, resolucao, urgencia, foto) VALUES (' + ocorrencia.idOcorrencia + ', "' + ocorrencia.descricao + '", "' + ocorrencia.data + '", "' + ocorrencia.resolucao + '", "' + ocorrencia.grauUrg + '", "' + ocorrencia.idOcorrencia + '.jpg"' +')';
```

The insert runs great, an I have all the data inserted in the DB, BUT "id" and "foto" (which were supposed to get equal values) are giving me different values by 2 or 3 miliseconds.

How can this happen, as I am not changing "ocorrencia.idOcorrencia" ?

This is beeing tested in an Android device.

EDIT: Tested on Windows browser and the problem doesn't appear to happen.

Thank you

Comment: So, after hours of monitor headbanging, we reached a conclusion.
I managed to look at my DB, and the values were wrong, so the error must be at insertion.
I was writing once as a number (to use as an ID), and another as a string. 
After trying the write as a string the 2 times, the values were always right, so i'll use a string as my ID.

We couldn't really get an explanation for this, only if there is a bug in MySQL in the direct conversion of a big string to number.

If someone could tell if this is a known issue, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you fill idOcorrencia on runtime? So the lag is producing this difference.
Try using a hash for the id or set it before running the SQL-query.

Comment: I am filling it on runtime, but I fill it just once and use it twice, so the value should be the same...

Comment: Sorry, I mean: you are filling it before the sql-statement?

Comment: Yes I am, and it still doesn't work that way.
I found a workaround, which i'll explain as a comment in my question. Be free to look at it.